# Submit button not working in my php's pizza website

Tags: php

[This is my pizza website page, It is pizza overview page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es39a.jpg) 
When I click this dropdown-list,and choose the type of pizza,the page does not redirect and does not show a specific pizza(which type I selected in dropdown-list), it shows all pizzas as it is,plz anyone can help me?

This is my code of submit button.

class pizzaController {

```
function CreatePizzaDropdownList()
{
    $pizzaModel = new PizzaModel();
    $result = "<from action = '' method = 'post' width = '200px'>
        please select a type:
        <select name = 'types'>
        <option value = '%'>All</option>
        " . $this->CreateOptionValues($pizzaModel->GetPizzaByTypes()).

            "</select>

            <input type = 'submit' value = 'Search'/> 
            </form>";


    return $result;

}
```

Comment: Start the form tag with <form> not </from> .... :)

Comment: please read the form basics before writing one.

Answer (score 1):

you declared a 'from' instead of a 'form'

change

```
$result = "<from action = '' method = 'post' width = '200px'>
```

to

```
$result = "<form action = '' method = 'post' width = '200px'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this to

```
$result = "<from action
```

this

```
$result = "<form action
```

As well as `action = ''` is **empty**

So **final code** would be

```
$result = "<form action = '' method = 'post' width = '200px'>
                please select a type:
                <select name = 'types'>
                <option value = '%'>All</option>
                    ". $this->CreateOptionValues($pizzaModel->GetPizzaByTypes())
                    ."</select>
                    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Search'/> 
            </form>";
```

Comment: Thanks everyone ,that is so silly mistake, I could not see for last few days...

Comment: @nikkiGupta acept it

Answer (score 0):

Write `<form action = '' method = 'post' width = '200px'>` instead of `<from action = '' method = 'post' width = '200px'>`

Modified code:

```
function CreatePizzaDropdownList()
{
    $pizzaModel = new PizzaModel();
    $result = "<form action = '' method = 'post' width = '200px'>
    please select a type:
    <select name = 'types'>
    <option value = '%'>All</option>
     " . $this->CreateOptionValues($pizzaModel->GetPizzaByTypes()).

           "</select>

            <input type = 'submit' value = 'Search'/> 
            </form>";       

    return $result;

}
```